# Accessing a badly named key in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, dictionary, escaping, key

I'm trying to access a key named `u'alt'` in a regular ole dict.

This naming convention is being returned by a webserver converted from HTML, so I have no say in redefining it.

```
print ship.attrs.keys()
print 'u\'alt\''
fullname = ship.attrs['u\'alt\'']
```

I have tried these lines and I get:

```
[u'name', u'value', u'alt', u'onchange', u'onfocus']
u'alt'
```

to `stdout`, so I know the variable is actually named this way (not a debugger issue), but my attempt to access it throws an exception even with the escape characters I pass in the keyname.

I have also tried defining the string with `""` double quotes instead.

Comment: It's just `ship.attrs[u'alt']`, the 'u' indicates it's a unicode string.

Comment: Probably should have occurred to me, I guess I just thought they wouldn't have been outputted that way from keys().

Answer (score 1):

The u is a string prefix indicating that the string supports Unicode characters. You want to do:

```
ship[u'alt']
```